# Load WP Admin scripts in a child theme functions file

Tags: functions

All, I'm using a plugin that enqueues some scripts in the admin section of wordpress. I want the same functionality built in a page template. I noticed the main difference between is it tries to use the load-scripts.php like this:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/bmt/multi-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-so&amp;load%5B%5D=rtable,postbox,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,jquery-ui-datepicker,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,&amp;load%5B%5D=iris,wp-color-picker,thickbox&amp;ver=4.0.1'></script>`

I want to specifically enqueue the same scripts from my functions.php child theme page. I specifically am worried about the postbox which sits in wp-admin/js/ How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `load-scripts.php` is concatenation of scripts from performance. It doesn't impact their functionality.

As far as I remember there is no way to reuse it at the site's front end. However simply looking up and enqueueing specific scripts you need will work just fine. They will just be loaded in normal fashion, without concatenation step.